# Can we Use multiple domain SSL Certificates on same IIS Web site?

Tags: ssl, iis

I have one website will be accessed by multiple different domains and will have separate SSL certificates for each.
Is it possible?
IF no then Is there any work around to install multiple certificates for single web site?

Comment: Would you mind mentioning the Windows version and IIS version? IIS 8 and above allows you to use SNI, which supports as many certificates as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having separate SSL certificate for each domain you can go for Multi domain certificate using Subject Alternative Names (SAN). It will be single certificate with multiple domains. Following image shows SAN certificate.

[image]

Image Courtesy : [DigiCert](https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm)

Answer (score 1):

SSL Certificate can only be issued to a **FQDN** (fully qualified domain name).

You better have elaborated your question with examples. By the way, let me guess and try to answer. As you said “You have one website – will be accessed by multiple different domains” - if I'm not wrong your are talking about one website which may be `www.domain.com` and multiple domains may be sub-domains like, `blog.domain.com`, `photos.domain.com` or `anything.domain.com`. If I have hit bulls eye, you don't need to get different SSL Certificates because all this domain can be secured with single Wildcard SSL Certificate. Wildcard SSL works on asterisk, so it will issued on *.domain.com and anything in place of asterisk will be covered.

**But make a note**, Wildcard SSL can work only on single level so something like `blog.photos.domain.com` will not be secured if you have got certificate for `*.domain.com`

**Different Scenario**: If you have something like this, domain.com, domain.co.uk, domain.com.eu etc. and it can be secured with different certificates. It may be costly deal if you have 20-30 or more domains, ideally you can get one multi-domain certificate to secure all these. [Visit this article](https://www.cheapsslshop.com/blog/difference-between-san-ssl-vs-wildcard-ssl-certificate) which will help you understand difference between Wildcard SSL and SAN functionality more deeply.